# Why should we use cin.get(ch) after taking input using cin.getline() or cin?

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
ofstream fout("student.dat",ios::out);
char name[20],ch;
float marks=0.0;
int i=0;

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
cout<<"Student"<<(i+1)<<" :\tName  :";
cin.get(name, 20);
cout<<"\t\tMarks :";
cin>>marks;
cin.get(ch);    //Significance of this statement-1?
fout<<name<<"\n"<<marks<<"\n";
}
fout.close();

ifstream fin("student.dat",ios::in);
cout<<"\n";
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
fin.get(name,20);
fin.get(ch);    //Significance of this statement-2?
fin>>marks;
fin.get(ch);    //Significance of this statement-3?
cout<<"Student Name :"<<name;
cout<<"\tMarks :"<<marks<<"\n";
}
fin.close();
return(0);
}
```

**INPUT-1:** Program takes input completely and gives satisfactory output.

**INPUT-2:** Program takes input for only first record and gives output just after taking first input (**When statement-1 is removed from program**).

```
 Student1 :      Name :Deepak     Marks :10
```

**OUTPUT-1:**

```
Student Name :Deepak      Marks :10
Student Name :Sandeep     Marks :20
Student Name :Vipin       Marks :30 
Student Name :Sachin      Marks :40
Student Name :Ashish      Marks :50
```

**OUTPUT-2:**

```
Student Name :Deepak      Marks :10
Student Name :    Marks :10
Student Name :    Marks :10 
Student Name :    Marks :10
Student Name :    Marks :10
```

So now my question is:

**1)** Why program doesn't take full input in 2nd case?

**2)** Which is responsible for this behavior, cin.getline() or cin?

**3)** I have partial idea (still need some clear explaination) that cin.get(ch) is used to clear buffer, but which are other functions which behave in similar way?

Comment: Remember that you end input with a newline, however that newline is still left in the input buffer after you read the input. [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is probably better to use for this (the linked reference have a very good example on how to skip until (and including) newline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are mixing formatted input such as `cin >> something;` and unformatted input such as `cin.get(...)`.

The formatted input skis all whitespace before reading data, and stops at the first whitespace after the input. [If you are reading digits, it will also stop on data that is incorrect, such as letters in your "number"].

These whitespaces are left in the input-stream, so if you are reading this using `cin.get(name, 20); cin>> number;`

```
 Name<space>Number<newline>
 Name<space>Number<newline>
```

the input for Number will stop at `<newline>`, and when you the next `cin.get(name, 20);` it will read an empty string, since `<newline>` is the first thing in the input stream. Adding `cin.get()` between those two statements will read that `<newline>`, and you will start reading `Name` on the next line

Comment: Why it doesn't work when I put statement-1 after `cin.get(name, 20);`?

Comment: define "doesn't work". It behaves differently, yes. But since the `newline` when you enter the data (I presume your data is `Deepak<newline>10<newline>`), there is only a single newline after your data, which is "used up" by `cin.get(name, 20);`.

Comment: Doesn't work means it works as it was behaving when statement-1 was removed from the program.  But now I can understand that the `<newline>` character will always be in buffer which is coming after `<number>` i.e `10<newline>` in this case and will be read by `cin.get()` in the next loop. So you mean the new line entered (whether input is taken using formatted or unformatted) after number will also be stored in stream?

Comment: So, the big difference is that `cin.get(name,20);` will not "remove" whitespace before the actual input, where `cin >> marks` will. So without the `cin.get()`, your `cin.get(name, 20);` reads an empty string. Next `cin >> marks;` will try to read a name as a number, and completely fail, and at that point the stream is in a fail state, so no further input will be taken from the stream until you use `clear()` to reset the streams status.

Comment: Please clear one more thing @Mats . When I am removing statement-2, program is working correctly. Also when I am replacing `fin.get(name,20);` with `fin.getline(name,20);` irrespective of whether statement-2 is there or not , program is still giving correct output. But we know that getline() removes delimiter (`<newline>` in this case) after reading input  whereas get() doesn't. How will you explain this?

Comment: Yes, because `fin >> marks` will skip all whitespace (newline counts as whitespace) before starting input, so the `fin.get()` will not alter the way the input works.